# Cant able to create activity using Claim API

Tags: guidewire, gosu

we have custom method in claimapi which will create activity and also add the document in claim. When we trigger that method we are getting below error message.
Error message :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot re-add Activity:-505001 since it has already been removed.  You must use bundle rollback to undo a remove.
Not sure what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In ClaimAPI method. Ensure you already have a current bundle. If it’s not available, then create a new bundle and create a new Activity.eti record and add it in the new bundle , then provide all mandatory column information. You should be able to do it.